# How to pass special characters in a function

Tags: angularjs, escaping, angularjs-controller

I am fairly new to angular, I am working on a POC of how to use modal in my application. Here is what I am doing:

I have controller which declares a function called `open` in the scope. The function open takes the url as the input. Now, the url that I need to pass in is dynamically created:

```
<a ng-click="open(/test/obj['test-attr']/update/)" href="/test/{{ obj['test-attr'] }}/update/">{{ obj['test-attr'] }}</a>
```

But this gives me a parse error. I am not sure how to pass the data to the controller.

Update:

The error is not because of quotations but because of the `/`. Is there a angular way to pass in special character into the function.

This is the error I get:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%205-5%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=open(%5C
```

Comment: replace your first single quotes to double quotes `ng-click="open(/test/obj['test-attr']/update/)"`

Comment: @worldask Make it an answer, no?

Comment: try to add escaping double quotes around your open argument `ng-click="open(\"/test/obj['test-attr']/update/\")"`

Comment: Tried still seeing the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not going to be solved by passing special characters. You are misguided.

The expression in the `ng-click` has syntax errors. Always remember that this is like "javascript code" (or "javascript expression" to be more precise).  I mean, would you type the following in javascript?

```
open(/test/obj['test-attr']/update/)
```

...this won't fly in javascript.  `/test/` and `/update/` are string literals and should be quoted. And to concatenate all those strings, use the good old + (plus) sign. To sum it up, it should look like:

```
open('/test/' + obj['test-attr'] + '/update/')
```

Here's the good syntax (and a working Plunker):

```
<a ng-click="open('/test/' + obj['test-attr'] + '/update/')" 
    href="/test/{{ obj['test-attr'] }}/update/">{{ obj['test-attr'] }}
</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uctqC5ByrR0wMvYUI5nX

---

Potential **second issue**: The following is **Off-Topic** but related to the code in the Plunker. It does not really answer the original question, but it is an issue I ran into while testing the Plunker example.

window.open() in Angular Expressions is not directly available.

These expressions are not exactly "Javascript", but rather "AngularJS Expressions".

It appears the code is attempting to call "open()" (a global javascript object - something not accessible in "AngularJS Expressions"). Angular keeps a very tight control over what's accessible globally.

I mean, you can only really access stuff in the $scope within these expressions. I thus created an "open" method in the $scope that simply calls $window.open().  ($window is the AngularJS wrapper to "window" for unit testing/mock, which is the Angular way of calling global javascript functions).

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.obj = { "test-attr": "testAttrData" };
  $scope.open = function() { $window.open.apply(null, arguments); }
});
```

---

I also suspect that you might have a **third issue**:  The `open()` will get called but that will not prevent the `href` action to take normal effect of reloading the page. If that's the case simply add an `$event.preventDefault();` in the `ng-click` expression:

```
ng-click="open('/test/' + obj['test-attr'] + '/update/'); $event.preventDefault();"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Regarding the second issue, I was using the open function declared in the scope of the controller.